# Configuring NGINX location to include subpaths

Tags: nginx, url-routing

I have an NGINX location block configured as below. This redirects to an angular Application and works fine. However, when I navigate to a subpath in the angular application such as `/path/subdir`, then NGINX returns 404.

Apparently this location block only sends requests to `/path` but not `/path/other` to Angular.

```
location /path {       
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I've tried variations such as these with the same result

```
location /path/
location /path/.*
```

How do I get NGINX so send all traffic sent to *anything* under `/path` to the same Angular application, so that the Angular application can then handle routing to sub-directories such as`/path/subdir`?

Comment: Your angular app is probably `/path/index.html`, so to force all URIs to the same location, try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /path/index.html;` thus replacing the 404 response with the location of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Well I ended up with this little horror show, but it seems to work.

```
location ~ ^/path(?:/(.*))?$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /path/index.html =404;
}
```